# Modify Expose button on my macbook for another shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, expose

The F3 button on my rMBP has a figure which shows 3 rectangles, pressing the button without the FN key initiates the Expose function. I want to modify that key for another function. However I cannot directly modify it via preferences because pressing that button does not register as a specific keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also change it to a normal F-key with [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/).

[image]

If anyone else is looking for a way to change it with KeyRemap4MacBook, just create a private.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, KeyCode::F19</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

The keycode constants are defined in [src/bridge/generator/keycode/data](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data). The test folder has a [checkbox.xml with all the predefined mappings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true).

Comment: What is the code to Hide window ? Which is CMD + H ?

Comment: `--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, KeyCode::H, VK_COMMAND` if you use a QWERTY-like keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), it should do what you're looking for.

Comment: That is too complex and not straightforward. Would appreciate another way.

Comment: It's really not complicated.  In the KeyRemap4MacBook preferences, just search for "Expose to F3", and that button will become the F3 button again, which "System Preferences" understands and can use for other shortcuts.